# Improvement of current & active suborg information dropdown

Tags: usability, toggle, drop-down-list

currently, I'm redesigning a component where big organizations that consist of smaller sub-organizations are able to switch between the organizations (by choosing organization as a current) to preview data indicated for this sub-organization. The green "dot" indicates the organization set as a current one and the toggle buttons next to organizations and departments indicates which data will be included on the platform. So to sum up: 1. user chooses the organization 2. user chooses which data he wants to include. The problem is that the current solution is not really user friendly. Does anyone have any suggestions regarding it? how could I improve it and still keep it as a dropdown?[image][image: idea of solution]

Comment: _"The problem is that the current solution is not really user friendly."_ What you have concluded from user feedback or other channels might be crucial for a helpful answer. Care to explain why you think/know it isn't user friendly?

Comment: yes of course. The current solution is not understandable. Users and even the company's employees don't understand the functionality of this dropdown menu. They don't understand what's a toggle for and what's the dot and how it influences data preview within the platform

Comment: Hence I thought to divide these 2 features into 2 sections. In the first section the user is able to preview/change the current active organization and in section two "include data" is able to choose/ decide which data should be included in data preview on the platform

Comment: so would you have any insights regarding the redesign or some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case where combining the steps of choosing the organization and choosing the dataset(s) isn't intuitive, at least from the perspective of the user trying to complete a particular task or workflow.

Depending on how the information architecture of the application is designed, and the different types of workflow possible, there might be simpler solutions. It seems strange that this is something that is done at the top level of the application, only because there are usually higher level admin or manager views that might allow you to see multiple organizations as well.

Without more details, and having to work with the constraint of showing everything in a dropdown, I suggest that using a checkbox rather than a toggle (if that's something confusing a lot of users in this context) might be a step in the right direction?